# Ember - images are not loaded properly during model change

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have designed a page using ember and running it over nodeJs.

This webpage contains a list of menu items. When user clicks any item, a webservice call will be made and their corresponding information (selected menu information) will be loaded to the new template.

For convenience, I placed my code template in JsBin - http://jsbin.com/apoRIhOQ/9/edit

```
<div class="thumb_image"><img  src="http://{image_url_path/{{unbound categoryInfo.imageName}}"/></div>
```

Here: http://{image_url_path}/ will be the image src location and imageName will be retrieved dynamically through webservice. (these imageNames will be changed dynamically based on the selected menu item).

My problem is:

First time, when user selects any item, all menu information are properly loaded in the new template (including image - images are loaded successfully). However, when user selects any item, **except image** all other information are loaded dynamically in template.

Can anyone please guide me why these images are not changed when model changed (images are rendered properly only first time).

Some additional information:
I debugged *categoryInfo.imageName* value and found that I am receiving a proper new image_name, however its not updated in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the link and transition to `CategoryRoute` with other params the controller object it's reused, you just change it's `content` or in your case `categoryInfo`.

Given you're using `{{unbound categoryInfo.imageName}}` Ember doesn't setup an observer for the `categoryInfo.imageName` property and therefore the template doesn't know that the property changed and that it needs to update (when you transition to the route with other params). Docs here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_unbound

What you hace to do is to bind the `categoryInfo.imageName` property to your template using

```
<img  {{bind-attr src="categoryInfo.imageName"}}/>
```

Also, you're prepending a part of the URL. So instead of binding to the property, bind to a computed property that depends on `categoryInfo.imageName`, like this (in you're model (or where you'd prefer)):

```
fullImageUrl: function () {
    return 'http://IMAGE_URL/%@'.fmt(this.get('imageName'));
}.property('imageName')
```

And in your template:

```
<img  {{bind-attr src="categoryInfo.fullImageUrl"}}/>
```